# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException on replaceAll using lookahead and backslash?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I'd like to escape all quotes (single and double) and backslashes of a string.

I'm trying to do this by a single call of myString.replaceAll. The regex to match and replace is `(?=['\"\\\\])` (escaped Java syntax), or more readable: `(?=['!\])` (unescaped syntax). 
I'm doing a lookahead, because I want to keep those quotes and backslashes, and just insert an escape character before each of them.

If I use `+` as an escape character, everything works like a charm (all strings below are in escaped Java syntax):

`"abc'def\"ghi\\jkl".replaceAll("(?=['\"\\\\])", "+")` results in `"abc+'def+\"ghi+\\jkl"`. Yay!

However, if I use a backslash as escape character, I'm getting a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException instead: `String index out of range: 1`.

The call looks like this:
`"abc'def\"ghi\\jkl".replaceAll("(?=['\"\\\\])", "\\\\")`

That's odd... Does the inserted backslash interfere somehow with the backslash within the lookahead regex? If so, how can I avoid this behavior?

Here is the full testing code:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;

public class RegexTest {
    @Test public void test() {
        assertEquals("abc\\'def\\\"ghi\\\\jkl", "abc'def\"ghi\\jkl".replaceAll("(?=['\"\\\\])", "\\\\"));
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: No repro on Oracle/Sun JVM from jdk5 to jdk8. Which JVM are you using? And on what platform? I pasted the code `"abc'def\"ghi\\jkl".replaceAll("(?=['\"\\\\])", "\\\\")` and it outputs `abc\'def\"ghi\\jkl` as expected.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using JRE 1.7.0_45-b18 on Windows 8.1 Pro.

Comment: Can you post the exact code which shows the problem? I tested your code (previous comment) on jdk7 but it outputs the result normally.

Comment: `import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;
public class RegexTest {
 @Test
 public void test() {
  assertEquals("abc\\'def\\\"ghi\\\\jkl", "abc'def\"ghi\\jkl".replaceAll("(?=['\"\\\\])", "\\\\"));
  }
}`

Comment: I tried a simple `System.out.println("abc\\'def\\\"ghi\\\\jkl".equals("abc'def\"ghi\\jkl".replaceAll("(?=['\"\\\\])", "\\\\")))` and can't reproduce this error on Java 7 update 45 (x64). I think it is not a problem with the Java library (assuming you are using Oracle/Sun JRE). The error probably comes from either the JVM or JUnit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, nhahtdh, thats helpful (and reassures me of my mental health ;-)